# How to get Single result on kendo.data.Datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-mvvm

I have an Odata result like this

```
        {"odata.metadata":"https://localhost/DocTalkMobileWebApiOData/odata/$metadata#MasterPatient/@Element","PatUniqueId":"39e713db-6a0e-4e59-bf7b-033f4fc47ad5",  "PatID":null,
"pat_lname":"White","pat_fname":"Peter","pat_mi":"     ","pat_ssn":"270787655","pat_dob":"08/07/1973","pat_sex":"M","pat_status":null,"priInsID":2,"secInsID":1,"PCPID":1,"InternalDrID":1,"EXPID":1,"EXPDate":"","pat_phone":null,"isNew":true,"imported":true,"byWhom":"dt","lastUpdate":"2011-03-30T09:41:57.36","changeStamp":"AAAAAAAAIUE=","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","currentMcp":"","currentVisitCount":-2,"otherId":"543674","pcpName":null,"hasChanges":true,"ProgramSource":null,"mrnID":"","createdBy":null,"createdDate":"2007-10-26T10:16:15","expLocation":null,"ethnicId":1,"prefLanguageId":1,"raceId":1
    }
```

and i tried to get this result via kendo.ui.datasource:

```
 newPatient = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: 'odata', // <-- Include OData style params on query string.
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: url + '/MasterPatient(guid\'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\')', // <-- Get data from here
                dataType: "json" // <-- The default was "jsonp"
            },

            parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);

                delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter.
                delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter.

                return paramMap;
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (data) {                 
                return data;
            },
            total: function (data) {                 
             return  data['odata.count']
            },
        }
    });
    newPatient.fetch(function () {
        kendo.bind($('#newPatientTab'), newPatient);
    });
```

But not sure why it always throw error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'slice'
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What to you mean by `Single Result` ? Will this odata url return one result always regardless of the odata query ?

Comment: @Jayantha yes i mean it's just a single record :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Kendo UI, DataSource works only with arrays. If you can change the server response to send something like this

```
[{"odata.metadata":"https://localhost/DocTalkMobileWebApiOData/odata/$metadata#MasterPatient/@Element","PatUniqueId":"39e713db-6a0e-4e59-bf7b-033f4fc47ad5","PatID":null,"pat_lname":"White","pat_fname":"Peter","pat_mi":"     ","pat_ssn":"270787655","pat_dob":"08/07/1973","pat_sex":"M","pat_status":null,"priInsID":2,"secInsID":1,"PCPID":1,"InternalDrID":1,"EXPID":1,"EXPDate":"","pat_phone":null,"isNew":true,"imported":true,"byWhom":"dt","lastUpdate":"2011-03-30T09:41:57.36","changeStamp":"AAAAAAAAIUE=","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","currentMcp":"","currentVisitCount":-2,"otherId":"543674","pcpName":null,"hasChanges":true,"ProgramSource":null,"mrnID":"","createdBy":null,"createdDate":"2007-10-26T10:16:15","expLocation":null,"ethnicId":1,"prefLanguageId":1,"raceId":1}]
```

then it will work fine.
N.B. It's in array format.

OR

You can wrap the single object into array on the client side, inside data function of the schema.

```
schema: {
  data: function(server-response) {
    return [server-response];
  }
}
```

The Kendo team should put more time on good Documentation.

Comment: Yes it works fine now.
I found another way to implement it:
  
   $.getJSON(url + '/MasterPatient(guid\'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\')', function (data) {
            newPatient = new kendo.observable(data);
            kendo.bind($('#newPatientForm'), newPatient);
        });

Comment: Using guid to call data is not a good idea. It's not generic.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it resolved your problem. Don't keep the question open.

Answer (score 3):

That means you are not using an odata source from the backed. You need to think about here do you really need a kendo odata source from the client in this case if your back-end not supported odata correcly.

See this response from  odata url, http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/?$format=json

It should return an array of object in the `value` field.
If you can't change the backed what you can do is to format the data in the Schema.data function

```
schema: {
        data: function (data) {                 
            return [data];
        },
```